# how to pass props using NAVLINK?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I tried using `aboubtProps`, but that's not working in `NAVLINK`.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
const location = {
  pathname: '/somewhere',
  state: { title: 'someTitle'}
}

<NavLink to={location}/>
```

And then you get it not from props but from location.state

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<NavLink
 to={{
     pathname:"/sum-patch",
     aboutProps:{title:"title Props"}             
  }}
```